# ORA-12560:TNS :protocol Adapter error after connecting with C# VS2012

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I am not even able to login using cmd after installing ODAC for C#, yesterday I had the same problem so I uninstalled all oracle products and installed again, now after installing ODAC again I am receiving same error.

Version of Database : Oralce 11.2.0.1.0
Version of ODAC : Oralce 11.2.0.1.2
OS:  windows 10

when I check tnsping my_service_name it gives

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name.

help me with this!

Comment: Can you logon with other tool, e.g. SQL*Plus? Does `tnsping.exe` work?

Comment: I am not able to login with SQL*Plus, but able to login with SQL developer.

Comment: Sorry for previous reply I am able to login with SQL Plus and SQL developer both,  but with Windows CMD line